# Accessing Import Filename

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, import

Is there any way to access the filename being used during an Import, say from within a Query, or - after the import - within AMPScript?  Are filenames stored in a place where users of the platform can get at them?

Answer (score 0):

No - Import definition attributes are not readily available in a DE or system data view.

It could be done through a custom extract.

Comment: Howdy David - To clarify, I wasn't looking for import attributes, I was looking for the actual filename used during the import that is currently in progress.  I know it's in there somewhere (automation studio shows each file processed during an execution), but yes, do not think it is available - I need it for some custom error reporting, so wanted to ask the group.