# SFMC - Automation SSJS Get filename and other metadata

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Currently, I have a file transfer and file import activity in my Automation. As part of this automation, I need to get the file name and number of records in the file for Audit purpose. Based on my research I see `BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER` could provide filename, but I am getting null value from it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var automationCustomerKey = "31e9a62f-02f5-123-9337-0e4xyz-2f0bcc"
var uploadedFileName = Variable.GetValue('BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER');

var logDE = 'Log_DE';

DataExtension.Init(logDE).Rows.Add({"File_Name":uploadedFileName, "No_of_records": "2", "File_received_on_Date": "05-12-2023" });

</script>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include some details about what you've attempted up to this point.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Added

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the substitution strings listed **[here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5)** can only be utilized in File Transfer and Import activities within FileDrop Automations. Anywhere else you use them, they will return null.

You could try the solution I put **[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349454/importdefinition-file-name)** that uses an undocumented API call to get history of the import to gather filename, but it comes with its own risks and some potential unexpected behaviors.

```
GET /automation/v1/imports/{{importActivityID}}/history
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```